# Change color line per line in JTextPane in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jtextpane

I have some problems with liner colors on my JTextPane. I use JWindowBuilder to make my interface.

The problem is that I need to change lines color depending on the value of a variable, for example, if the variable is 10, I have to put this line on green, but if the variable is 20 I have to put this line on red.

I have this piece of code but it only change all lines to the same color, no an especific line, I mean, if the last line is red and I change the color, it changes all lines to red:

```
for(int i=0; i<l_container.getMissionSampleCount(0); i++)  
                {

                 String aux = textArea.getText();
                 aux += "\n Muestra "+ (i+1) + ": " + dff.format(lista[i]);
                 textArea.setText(aux);

                if ((lista[i] > maxTemperature) && (maxTemperature != minTemperature))
                    textArea.setForeground(Color.RED);
                else if ((lista[i] < maxTemperature) && (maxTemperature != minTemperature))
                    textArea.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
                else 
                    textArea.setForeground(Color.GREEN); 
                }
```

Can someone help me? Thanks! :)

Comment: that I need to change lines color depending on the value of a variable - read Oracle tutorial about JTextComponents, there must be working code example with HightLigther

Comment: thanks, but i can't use textArea.HighLigther, I don't understand what you suggest. I need to change the color of my lines on the JTextPane.

Comment: after your question is edited, with, maybe important details 1. for better help sooner post an SSCCE/MCVE, short, runnable, compilable, with hardcoded value for JTextPane called as textArea 2. maybe to use JTextArea (is designated for simple and undecorated JTextComponent), 3 otherwise (without an SSCCE/MCVE) look at, search for events from DocumentListener (API, Oracle tutorial for working code example)

Comment: I think on this solution:  StyleConstants.setForeground(sas, Color.RED);
       textArea.setParagraphAttributes(sas, false); but i cannot do some paragraphs, can you help me?

Comment: How do you recognize the line to change ? Is it like the nth line, or is it the line where the cursor currently is ? Or do you want to apply for each line a specific color in the whole current content of the document ?